# Drag and drop doesn't work between host and VirtualBox on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My host is 64 bit Windows 7 bit where my VirtualBox is running 32 bit Windows 7. I have installed guest services and I have enabled drag and drop in Settings >> General >> Advance to bidirectional.

I can copy/paste text file between host and virtual box and copy/paste or drag/drop doesn't work.

I have tried one of the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63420/how-to-fix-virtualboxs-copy-and-paste-to-host-machine) by Sam there (Kill VBoxTray.exe) but it didn't work. I see other threads like [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=52172) but there are no answer.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using?  Can you drag and drop from the guest VM to the host?

Comment: Also from VBox's documentation (latest version): "Limitations: On Windows hosts, dragging and dropping content from UAC-elevated (User Account Control) programs to non-UAC-elevated programs and vice versa is now allowed. So when starting VirtualBox with Administrator privileges then drag and drop will not work with the Windows Explorer which runs with regular user privileges by default."

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am using the latest 5.1.6 The drag and drop doesn't work in either direction.

Comment: To install guest services, when your virtual OS is running from Virtual box menu select Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image. Guest editions is required to have drag & drop and shared clipboard

Comment: In my case, I had to reinstall guest services and restart the virtual system after updating virtualbox on the host, so my versions matched again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open windows explorer as administrator and drag from there:

- open Windows directory
- Locate explorer.exe
- Right click, run as administrator

Tested on 5.1.8, host and guest both windows 7 x64, using guest additions.

Note: You might need to shutdown and start again the guest os, at least for me the guest bugs badly when I try to drag a file from a non UAC explorer window.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I also had to reboot my VM to make it work. Before reboot though, copy/paste messed the VM, the explorer on it will not work properly after copy/paste..double click edited folder instead of opening. Reboot fixed those issues.

Comment: And FYI, explorer.exe is typically in C:\Windows

Comment: It did not work for me. The guest is always stuck with "Dropping data... 0%"

Comment: This does not work, at least not anymore.

Comment: For me drag & drop from the Desktop or from an elevated Explorer didn't worked. I used another file commander (Total Commander) elevated and drag & drop worked.