# Drag and drop doesn't work in VirtualBox, host is Windows 10, guest is Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox

My host is Windows 10 and my guest is Windows 7. I enabled Devices > Drag And Drop > Host to Guest. I failed.

Then I tried the [this](https://superuser.com/a/1145469/764348) method which states I should open Windows Explorer.exe as administrator. I did it on both machines. Both it didn't work.

How can I make drag and drop work?

Thanks

**EDIT:** VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2) 
No extensions. Just default installation.

Comment: Please provide specifics on the version of Vbox you are using.  Do you have the current extensions installed?  Update your question to include this information, comments which contain in this information, won't be noticed by most people.

Comment: Does that mean you don't have the vbox additions installed?

Comment: I only installed standard VBox in host (Win10). I didn't installed anything in guest(Win7).

Comment: Which is the reason drag and drop functionality isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just default installation.

Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest OS (W7) ? They are needed for, basically, any interaction between the guest OS and the "outside world". That includes drag-and-drop, file copy, automatic screen resize, et cætera.

Comment: Thank you. I'll install Guest addition and make you informed later.

Comment: You need to visualize the virtual machine as a computer that is completely isolated from the outside world, except for keyboard & mosue input. Theoretically, a guest operating system can't even know it is in a virtual machine and not a physical machine (this is why sandboxing, or running software in a VM, is a good way of preventing your main OS from being infected). The "Guest Additions" (or VMware Tools, or anything), is like a little straw you put between your main OS and the guest OS that allows it to communicate and transmit more complex data, like files, screen resolution changes, etc.

Comment: I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 5.1.26r117224. But I have still problem with Drag&Drop. So sad